Resistor Values for an LT1170 voltage regulator
I am trying to create a schematic for an LT1170 to make a stable power supply at 13.5V. This is in order to regulate an unregulated wall wart PSU for a older device. The original supply is a transformer with a center tapped secondary, two diodes, a smoothing cap and a bleeder resistor. Just a dead simple, unregulated full bridge rectifier.
The output of the power supply worries me because it varies under load and I would imagine it must change with the wall supply. So I want to install a simple voltage regulator inside the device, after the power jack, in order to keep it steady.
This is also just an exercise for myself to learn, so if it seems overkill, it's not a concern for me.
I found the LT1170 is capable of the 13.5V, 1.5A typical load, so I got the datasheet and drew something up, but I'm not sure how to specify the resistor values for the feedback circuit. I know I need 13.5V on the input, and the transformer supply is going to be giving that (nominally) under load and maybe a touch higher, but it could dip or spike a bit. This is what I came up with, and the diagram from the datasheet is attached. The whole datasheet is here How do I choose the resistor values for R1 and R2?
TIA
EDIT: I have been searching around, and I found that maybe the right thing to do is to choose values that keep the feedback pin at the datasheet specified 1.224V. If that's the case, and I want 13.5V on the output, that would mean that I need to choose a divider that satisfies that voltage. Keeping R2 at 1.24k, that would mean I need something around 12.2k for R1. Does that sound correct?
    VIN ~13.5V             ___
     o----------o----------UUU--------o         o---------o--o VOUT 13.5V
                |          L1         |         |         |
    C2      ||  |          50uH       |         |         |
  0.1uF  o--||--o                     |     \]  |         |
         |  ||  |                     |  .--|]--| C4      |
         |      |    .-------------.  |  |  /]+ | 1000uF  |
         |  \]  |    |             |  |  |      | 25V     |
         o--|]--o    |   LT1172    |  |  |      |         |
    C1   |  /]+ |    |             |  |  |      |         |
  220uF  |      o----|5 Vin        |  |  |     _|_ D1     |
   25V   |           |             |  |  |     /_\ 1N5821 |
         o---.       |             |  |  |      |         |
         |   |       |        VSW 7|--o--|------o         |
         |  --- C3   |             |     |          ___   |
         |  --- 1uF  |             |     |      o--|___|--o
         |   |       |             |     |      |    R1
         |   |       |         FB 3|-----|------o  10.74k?????
         |  .-.      |             |     |      |
         |  | |R3    |             |     |     .-.
         |  | |1k    |             |     |     | |R2
         |  '-'      |             |     |     | |1.24k
         |   |       |             |     |     '-'
         |   '-------|             |     |      |
         |           |             |     |      |
         |        o--|1 GND        |     |      |
         o--------|--|6 E1         |     |      |
         |        o--|8 E2         |     |      |
         |           '-------------'     |      |
         '---------------o---------------o------'
                         |
                        GND



The ascii art takes me back, but we do have a schematic editor available.

What's the DC output from the wall wart?

Just as an aid, I made a web page for divider resistor calculation years ago.  If you enter the FB voltage (1.224), the output voltage, and the resistor tolerance you want to use, it will find the best standard values (and output tolerance) to get the voltage you're looking for: http://www.syncbuck.com/

The DC output of the wall wart is an unregulated transformer with a center tap on the secondary that outputs about 14VDC under load, but it fluctuates. That's the reason I'm looking into this regulator. The voltage straddles the required 13.5V under most conditions

Thanks John. That's helpful. I think I'm getting it now. Although I realize my topology choice may be poor as the input voltage will straddle the output voltage.

Here is a simulation (LTSpice) with LT1170 (internal file, Applications).


Thanks for the simulation. I have LTSpice on my PC, but I'm still new to it.I was able to find the example in the program.
